# Delete button for each row in a php table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table on my page view_feedback.php

```
//Retrieve feedback info from database
                $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM feedback ORDER BY ID desc");
                $query->execute();

                //Display feedback info in table 
                echo "<table id='user' class='table table-bordered'>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Message</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>";

                while ($dbRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $id = $dbRow['ID'];
                    $name = $dbRow['Name'];
                    $email= $dbRow['Email'];
                    $message = $dbRow['Message'];

                { echo "<tr>
                    <td>$id</td>
                    <td>$name</td>
                    <td>$email</td>
                    <td>$message</td>
                    <td>" . " <input type='submit' action='view_feedback.php' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >" .  "</td>
                  </tr>"
                  ;}

                }
                echo "</table>";
```

And then i have this code to execute the delete:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $query = $db->prepare (DELETE * FROM feedback WHERE ID = ?)
    $query->execute($id);
}
```

The table displays fine but when i click the delete button nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='submit' action='view_feedback.php' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >
```

It should have a name = 'delete' so that the $_POST could retrieve it:

```
<input type='submit' name = 'delete' action='view_feedback.php' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >
```

Comment: Just did that and the button still does nothing when clicked. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where you execute the delete, is the variable 'id' set? I don't see a $id = $_POST['delete'];